# CQ5.5 order standard HTTP filters deployed as OSGI components

Tags: aem, sling

In CQ5.5 How I can order 2 standard HTTP Filters deployed as OSGI components?

The issue is that the 2 filters have to run in order where FilterA should run first and then FilterB in sequence.

How I can order my 2 filters in sequence?

Do you know if there is any OSGI or SCR property with which I can order the 2 filter so that one should run after another?

For example:

Filter A

```
@Component
@Service
@org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties({
@Property(name = "pattern", value = "/.*"),
@Property(name = Constants.SERVICE_RANKING, intValue = 99999, propertyPrivate = false)
})
public class FilterA implements implements javax.servlet.Filter {
}

FilterB

@Component
@Service
@org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties({
@Property(name = "pattern", value = "/.*"),
@Property(name = Constants.SERVICE_RANKING, intValue = 100000, propertyPrivate = false)
})
public class FilterB implements implements javax.servlet.Filter {
}
```

I would like to run FilterA first and then FilterB.

If I deploy the above filters as OSGI bundles on CQ5.5 I only see FilterB is triggered on the HTTP White board console. I do not see FilterA being even invoked during my CQ5.5 login request flow.

Thanks.

Comment: I have figured out I can use service.ranking to order the filters as OSGI components.

[Sling service.ranking][1]


  [1]: http://sling.apache.org/site/filters.html

Comment: you should post this as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Check http://sling.apache.org/site/filters.html
Service Ranking is what you're looking for. Also note on sling/cq5 you can see which filters are active and their ranking by looking /system/console/config and Sling Servlet Filters.

Also see filter-scope and the changes made to introduce pattern based scopes ([SLING-1213](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-1213), [SLING-1734](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-1734))

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a filter.order attribute to your service:

```
@Property(name="filter.order",intValue=-2500)
```

The lower the value, the further ahead in the chain the filter will be placed.

Comment: From the sling filter docs it _seems_ as though this was replaced by service.ranking.  The [filter.order property is supported up to and including 2.1.0](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html#support-in-sling-engine-210).  However, some of the sling filters still use this property and not service.ranking.  The filter.order property is only used if service.ranking is not present.  See [SLING-1735](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-1735)

Comment: Thanks diffa you are correct service.ranking is the right way to order standard filters for Apache Felix Http Service Whiteboard implementation